# How to iterate over a mailbox in SystemVerilog without removing its elements?

Tags: iteration, system-verilog

I have a mailbox of type ethernet packet. I have randomly put data into the mailbox. Now I want to print each element of mailbox without removing the element. 
I tried doing **try_peek** but it always points to the first element, so it always prints the first element. the **get()** method removes the element, so at the end of for loop the mailbox is empty. 
Is there a way that I can  iterate over a mailbox in SystemVerilog without removing its elements?

```
for (int i=0; i<=9; i++)
                begin
                    mbox_pkt.try_peek(pkt1);
                    $display("mbox_pkt=%p", pkt1);
                end
```

mbox_pkt is a mailbox of type ethernet packet.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to access elements of a mailbox without removing the next element with a get or try_get.